# Show that $E[1_P|X_n]E[1_F|X_n]=E\{1_PE[1_F|X_n]|X_n \} $

Tags: probability-theory

> Given a sequence $X_n $ of random variables show that for any $P \in
> > \sigma(X_1,...,X_{n-1 } )$ and any $F \in \sigma(X_{n+1 },X_ {n+2
> > }...) $
>
> $$E[1_P|X_n]E[1_F|X_n]=E\{1_PE[1_F|X_n]|X_n \} $$

All I can do is the following: noting that $E[1_F|X_n] $ is a $\sigma(X_n ) $-measurable random variable we have from the second defining property of conditional expectation that

$$E[1_PE[1_F|X_n]]=E[E[1_P|X_n]E[1_F|X_n]]$$

But where to go from this (if this is the right approach to begin with)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the pull out property of conditional expectation..? $$\mathbb{E}(X Y \mid \mathcal{F})) = Y \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F})$$ for any $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variable $Y$ (...satisfying certain integrability conditions to ensure that $XY \in L^1$)

Comment: Yes I do. How so I use it here?

Comment: Take a look at the right-hand side. You need something $\sigma(X_n)$-measurable which you can pull out side the conditional expectation. Any idea?

Comment: okey trivial! But thanks!